# How to generate a WPF form that allows editing of any object

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, dynamically-generated

What I'm trying to accomplish is to dynamically create a form that allows editing all the fields and properties of an object (recursively).

I already managed to do this in some simple cases.

Problems I encountered so far:

- Hiding the automatically generated backing fields of properties (I do this by checking if the names starts with "<" which was the only difference between a generated backing field and a regular field I found (I could mark manually created backing fields with an attribute to filter them))
- Display lists and dictionaries. They work but not especially well.

I found solutions (like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87715/Native-WPF-4-PropertyGrid/)) that only worked with properties and didn't display properties/fields of a nested user class.

Is there an existing solution that:

- works with fields and properties
- and allows editing of fields/properties of arbitrary type (maybe in a new window)?

Comment: a backing field has no name constraints - they can be named whatever they want..

Comment: @Default: If I create an automatic property like this "public string MyString {get;set;}" the compiler creates a field backing this property which is also contained in the reflected fields of the class. This was called something like "<MyString>_backingField". Since normal fields don't start with "<" I used this to distinguish them.

Comment: You could try this property grid: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home. I doubt it supports fields, but you may be able to modify it to suit your purposes.

Comment: May I ask why fields?  The common convention is a public property is for outside use and field is internal.

Comment: I want allow the user to "edit" some object in certain circumstances and not all classes are classes I can edit.

Comment: So these classes expose fields and properties?  Can you inspect for only public?